# Cannot assign Custom Class to UITableView in IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a custom class that derives from (a base class that derives from) UIViewController and UITableViewDelegate that I want to assign to my table view.

I know it's assignable, because I've used this pattern elsewhere in my project, but entering the name in Custom Class doesn't work (it get's erased when I hit Enter). Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldnt your BaseClass derive from UITableviewcontroller? If you want to conform to the UITableViewDelegate protocol, why would you want it to derive from UiViewcontroller?

Comment: The other classes deriving from the BaseClass aren't necessarily UITableViewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works, but if I temporarily make my class derive from UITableViewController instead of my BaseViewController, I can assign the custom class in interface builder. Then, I can switch back to deriving from my BaseViewController and everything will still function correctly.

Could be a separate question, but any idea why this works?